# What causes distortion in my Roland 4500?

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard, distortion

Roland 4500 sounded normal until I stopped using it when I was sick. Now there's distortion (gravely not scratchy). Can heavy dust be responsible?

Comment: Can you please edit some more information onto your question, such as how long it was unused, have you seen a lot of dust on the speakers (you can vacuum it off) etc